# woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation in ajax

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use this hook to add a custom field to woocommerce single products pages:

```
function ardv_display_product_custom_form() {

    echo '<input type="text" id="first-name" name="first-name" value="">';

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'ardv_display_product_custom_form' );
```

and then this hook to validate my input:

```
function ardv_custom_forms_inputs_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {

    if( isset( $_POST['first-name'] ) && empty( $_POST['first-name'] ) ) {
        $passed = false;
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter your first name.', 'simple' ), 'error' );
    }
    return $passed;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'ardv_custom_forms_inputs_validation', 10, 3 );
```

It's working with no problem. But when I click on add to cart button the product page refresh and then the error massages appear. is there any way to do this in ajax without refreshing the page?

Comment: If the page is refreshing, then you're not using AJAX

Comment: Yes, I'm not using AJAX. I want to do it by AJAX. It would be appreciated if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

In case somybody else face this problem:
I used [jquery validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) instead of using woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation hook.